# PHP MVC - SESSION not persistent

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller

I ran into a problem with my PHP session lately.

For developing I am using a MVC (Model View Controller) structure.

The important files:

```
├───classes
    ├───controllers
    │       base_controller.php
    |       ...
    │
    ├───helpers
    ├───parts
    └───views
            login_view.php
            register_view.php
            ...
index.php
```

Problem: **login_view.php** can't "find" the $_SESSION["currentUser"], that is set in **base_controller.php**.

Explanation: The session is started in the index.php **before** the base_controller.php is loaded.

```
<?php
require_once("php/classes/DB.class.php");
require_once("php/classes/Functions.class.php");
require_once("php/classes/User.class.php");

session_start();

require_once("php/classes/ErrorMsg.class.php");
require_once("php/controllers/base_controller.php");
?>
```

The $_SESSION["currentUser"] is set in the base_controller.php after successful login. The $user object is stored in the Session. *(No, not serialized, I know. But on purpose.)*

```
if(login($username, $password)){
    $m = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $user;
    require_once('php/views/register_view.php');
    exit();
}
```

The session is **successfully created**. Register_view.php is displayed and I am able to use the session.

When I reload the page however, and login_view.php is showed again, I can not use the session at all. **Also, it seems that the base_controller.php itself can't use the session too.**

The important parts of my base_controller.php:

```
$user = new User();
$error = new ErrorMsg();

...

//Button Login Pressed
if(isset($_POST["submit_login"])){
    if(isset($_POST["login_username"]) && isset($_POST["login_password"])){
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["login_username"], ENT_QUOTES);
        $password = $_POST["login_password"];

        if(login($username, $password)){
            $m = "";
            $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $user;
            require_once('php/views/register_view.php');
            exit();
        }
        else{
            $m = $error->WriteError("Login nicht möglich. Falsche Zugangsdaten.", "base_controller -> function login", "");
            require_once('php/views/login_view.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}

...

//Does not work. isset($_SESSION["currentUser"]) returns FALSE
if(isset($_SESSION["currentUser"])){
    if($_SESSION["currentUser"]->isLoggedIn()){
        require_once('php/views/register_view.php');
        exit();
    }
}

// Display Login Page
require_once("php/views/login_view.php");
```

So to summarize it: **register_view.php can** use $_SESSION["currentUser"], **login_view.php and base_controller.php cannot**.

I've tried to

```
echo var_dump($_SESSION['currentUser']);
```

same as

```
echo var_dump($_SESSION[]);
```

but **both return NULL or an empty array** when used in **login_view.php** -> But give **valid results in register_view.php**

Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this non-persistent session?

I really hope I just made a very foolish mistake. You're welcome to laugh constructively. ^^

Comment: Make dealing with sessions through a class method is better in MVC, all MVC frameworks do that.

Comment: So like a class Session with method CreateSession() that does session_start()?
Thanks for the suggestion, I'll read into it :)

Comment: As an additional hint, the Create Session functionality should be in the class instructor, and this class by any mean in your framework should be loaded `bootstrapping` in the beginning of the execution to make sure session accessibility is available for every aspect of your framework, such as models, views, helpers, controllers, etc.

Comment: Do NOT include solution in the question. Edit it out and post it as an answer instead.

Comment: I agree with @walther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem solved!

**How I solved it:**

Please make sure to read the original problem so you understand the fix.

The main problem was, that I tried to save the object $user directly into the $_SESSION. Due to the *__PHP_Incomplete_Class* the whole thing did not work. I fixed it with storing the User-Data in an array.

```
$_SESSION["currentUser"] = array("id"=>$user->GetUserId(),"firstname"=>$user->GetFirstname(),"lastname"=>$user->GetLastname(),"username"=>$user->GetUsername(),"lastlogin"=>$user->GetLastLogin(),"group"=>$user->GetGroup(), "class"=>$user->GetClass());
```

Now, the advantage of directly editing and using functions from the Class however, is gone. I can not use something like

```
foreach($_SESSION["currentUser"] as $key => $obj){
   return '<p>'.$obj->getContent().'</p>';
}
```

anymore. Also, I can't directly set fields in the User Class anymore.

```
$_SESSION["currentUser"]->checkIfOnline();
```

However, to "log out" I just have to delete the session.

```
unset($_SESSION["currentUser"]); //To delete User session
```

Once all user-data is saved in a DB, it's perfect that way **Session deleted = User logged out.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling start_session in login_view.php too?
start_session should always be called before using session variables.

Comment: I've tried that too, yes. But in MVC one global session_start() in the index.php is enough. Because all other resources are loaded after that. Sadly didn't work.

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite for your urls? Maybe the session cookie url is wrong, as getting saved in you.url/login and not in your.url

Comment: I am using my .htaccess, yes. But the area of validity of this Session is the entire URL. Checked that with the Chrome extension "EditThisCookie". So the mistake is not there either.